# Is it possible to get the HTML code from WebView

Tags: html, android, webview

I would like to preemptively get the HTML code of a webpage that is to be loaded in a `webView`, parse it using regex, and display only the HTML code that I want, while letting the webpage still think it has loaded everything.

Is there any way to do that in the `WebViewClient.onLoadResource()` or similar methods?

EDIT: I tried this:

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface  
 {  
      @SuppressWarnings("unused")  
         public void showHTML(String html, Context context)  
         {  
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)  
                 .setTitle("HTML")  
                 .setMessage(html)  
                 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)  
             .setCancelable(false)  
             .create();  
               pageHTML = html;
         }  
 }

@Override
    public void customizeWebView(final ServiceCommunicableActivity activity, final WebView webview, final SearchResult mRom) {
        mRom.setFileSize(getFileSize(mRom.getURLSuffix()));
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        MyJavaScriptInterface interfaceA = new MyJavaScriptInterface();
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(interfaceA, "HTMLOUT");  
        WebViewClient anchorWebViewClient = new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override  
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
            {  
                /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */  
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<h2>Winning Sc.+</h2></div>(.+)<br>", Pattern.DOTALL);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageHTML);
                matcher.find();
```

The interface is never called

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had to use HttpClient. no cookies required, just parsing for html:

```
private String getDownloadButtonOnly(String url){
    HttpGet pageGet = new HttpGet(url);

    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
        public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String html; 

            if (entity != null) {
                html = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                return html;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    pageHTML = null;
    try {
        while (pageHTML==null){
            pageHTML = client.execute(pageGet, handler);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<h2>Direct Down.+?</h2>(</div>)*(.+?)<.+?>", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageHTML);
        String displayHTML = null;
        while(matcher.find()){
            displayHTML = matcher.group();
        }

    return displayHTML;
}

    @Override
    public void customizeWebView(final ServiceCommunicableActivity activity, final WebView webview, final SearchResult mRom) {
        mRom.setFileSize(getFileSize(mRom.getURLSuffix()));
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebViewClient anchorWebViewClient = new WebViewClient()
        {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                String downloadButtonHTML = getDownloadButtonOnly(url);
                if(downloadButtonHTML!=null && !url.equals(lastLoadedURL)){
                    lastLoadedURL = url;
                    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, downloadButtonHTML, null, "utf-8", url);
                }
            }
```

Comment: @pageHTML = client.execute(pageGet, handler);

what is client?

Comment: nevermind,
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

Comment: @Aymon Fournier- How i get just some line of html-source code of webpage ? if i get full source page it may get so much time and i dont need to get all line, can you help me? thx very much

Comment: Doesn't work when a page needs JavaScript to get data

Answer (score 5):

Here is a tutorial of [Extracting HTML from a WebView](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/) don't forget to read the warning in the end of the tutorial.

Comment: webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");  
  WebViewClient anchorWebViewClient = new WebViewClient()
     {
   @Override  
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
   {  
       /* This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading. */  
       webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @JavascriptInterface before
public void showHTML(String html, Context context)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a chance to influence server part where you receive a page from, you can ask to redirect to a particular page in case of error. In your WebViewClient you can detect this redirect and use it a signal of error.