# How to get the webview's content which was clicked on the webview

Tags: android-webview

I want to add the bookmark function to my app, when I clicked on the webview which display the HTML files (The file's main part is string), I want to capture the first line of the content which display on the screen. Anyone knows the answer?

Thanks very much in advance.

-Shawn

Answer (score 1):

you can identify the some content of the page as It contains img tag or not 
Use this API of webView click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html)

```
 WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();
 int i=hr.getType() ;
```

and use the int values of this class for the content

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

If there is a link into the WebView and you want to do a specific action when the user click on this link you must catch the link click using the following code:

Somewhere in your activity code (commonly in the onCreate method):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, R.layout.news_details);
    ...
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    ...
}
```

And the WebViewClient class:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading url= " + url);
        }
        if ( the url is like you want) {
            // TODO: add the code to do what you need to do with the url
            // the webview should not do anything with this link.
            return true;
        } else {
            // let the webview normally handle the link
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If what you want to do is get the actual displayed content of the WebView, there is no API to do that.

Have a look on those post:

[Is it possible to get the HTML code from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479833/is-it-possible-to-get-the-html-code-from-webview)

[Retrieve webview content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842339/retrieving-webview-content-android-app)

Both redirect on this website:

http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/