# I got error NetworkOnMainThreadException on sendMail method...how to solve it?

Tags: android

i am using email authentication mailing some file in android bt i got error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException hw to solve it... code is

```
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;

    public class MailSenderActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {   
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                            "This is Body",   
                            "user@gmail.com",   
                            "user@yahoo.com");   
                } catch (Exception e) {   
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                } 

            }
        });

    }
}
     GmailSender.java





     public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

JSSE Provider

```
/*
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */



 /**

 * @author Alexander Y. Kleymenov
 * @version $Revision$
 */


import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but i got error NetworkOnMainThreadException on sendMail method...hw to solve it??

Comment: you can't connect to internet on Main thread, use `AsyncTask` method for sending and getting data to internet

Comment: You can't perform your Network UI operation on main thread. So need to use AsyncTask .

Comment: Check this answer [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: how to use myAsyncTask in my main thread....i m using like dis private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> { protected String doInBackground(String... params) { publishProgress("Sleeping..."); try { GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("design@mindkey.in", "mind1!@#"); sender.sendMail("This is Subject", "This is Body", "design@mindkey.in", "design@mindkey.in"); } return ???; } can u fix my problem and upload here........plz help me

Comment: Did you even think about searching first?  There are HUNDREDS of Q&A for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,you have to use separate Thread to connect the network so use asynchronous task to handle the network. It will solve your issue.

Comment: hw to use asynchronous in my main class  MailSenderActivity ...hw wll do?? plz help me...

Comment: @aish http://subinsebastien.tumblr.com/post/10319834334/simple-asynctask-example-in-android  check this link and do the network operation in doinbaground method

Comment: i saw d example bt i didnt understand how to use myAsyncTask in my main thread....i m using like dis private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      publishProgress("Sleeping..."); 
      try {
     GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("design@mindkey.in", "mind1!@#");
      sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
              "This is Body",   
              "design@mindkey.in",   
              "design@mindkey.in");  
      } 
      return ???;
     } help me

Comment: can u fix my problem and upload here........plz help me

Comment: what is your issue, u have to run network operation in doinbackground method

Comment: issue is dat i m using a AsyncTaskRunner class in my MailSenderActivity class and in AsyncTaskRunner class i m using GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("design@mindkey.in", "mind1!@#"); sender.sendMail("This is Subject", "This is Body", "design@mindkey.in", "design@mindkey.in") bt wht to do return through AsyncTaskRunner class?? didnt understand

Comment: can u say dat how to send html code in body part?? any idea

Comment: @aish can u ask ur question briefly

Comment: @aish check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007911/android-html-code-from-webview