# Get the html from the webview, and then manipulate it and load back

Tags: android

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479833/is-it-possible-to-get-the-html-code-from-webview
```

got many links to get the html code from webview, but need to manipulate it and then again load it back.
Is it possible to do that.if yes, please give some ideas.
I have not that much idea of java script.

Comment: load it back as in... have that page modified for anyone else who views it? Or load it so that the device you just downloaded to can view the manipulated page?

Comment: what kind of manipulation are you looking for?

Comment: @Martin yes to load it, so that the device which has downloaded can view the manipulate page.

Comment: @AndroSelva change some values and then again load the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
 webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"N\").value = 'dfdfdfd';"+
                     "document.getElementById(\"Pass\").value = 'fdfdfde'");
```

where "N" and "Pass" are control names in the html

I have done it in onPageFinished().

Answer (score 1):

you can  load from an HTML string:

```
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```