# Get the HTML code from loaded WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have something like this

```
final WebView w=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
w.loadUrl("http://somepage.com");
```

Is there any way to get the html page that is shown in the WebView at some moment of time ?
I want to get this html page as string variable.

The point is I want to get the html code after the javascript is executed on a client side...

any guidelines ?

Comment: I tried that solution already , but it does not work for me, maybe it is problem with android versions...

Comment: Considering that you just accepted an answer which is the same as the duplicate, I find your response surprising.

Comment: well people say that this is stupid question and they asked for close so..., I still can not read the html text from the webview, but I guess this is problem only on my phone, cause everybody else say that is working fine , that is why I marked as answered.

Comment: Bear in mind that if your app has `android:targetVersionSdk` set to 17 or higher, you need to add the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation to any methods you wish to expose to JavaScript via `addJavascriptInterface()` (e.g., the `processHTML()` method in the answer that you accepted here).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way I know;

decleration javascript handler in your activity

```
class LoadListener{
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        Log.e("result",html);
    }
}
```

after configure your webview;

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new LoadListener(), "HTMLOUT");
```

than webview client;

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                return true;
        }              

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
        }
});
```

Comment: For API levels higher than 17, you need to add @JavascriptInterface annotation for that to work, otherwise it will not be called.

Comment: does this work in API 21 and Adroid 4.2.2? Doesn't seem to be working for me Android 4.2.2 with API 21. But it does work in android 4.4.2 and API 21.

Comment: I tried the code. After view.loadUrl() in onPageFinished() is done, onPageFinished() is not called. How could we know the inner loadUrl() is done?

Comment: Is your url wait for request string? Maybe Same params? Could you post your request address?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: window.HTMLOUT.processHTML is not a function", source:  (1)

Comment: I cant get your problem. I need more details.

Comment: You need to put `@JavascriptInterface` before each function of the class that you provide to `addJavascriptInterface` . See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24060790/878126

Comment: This can not show `iframe` content

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the code is by using the HttpClient as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479833/is-it-possible-to-get-the-html-code-from-webview/3482047#3482047). Another solution is given in the following [blog](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/10/calling-javascript-function-from.html).

Comment: This will not bring along cookies etc.