# How to deal with javascript multi-object function with WebView component in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Now I need to use webview component to load a HTML page and deal with component function.
The content in HTML page is  ,

you can see there is a multi-object (webkit.messageHandlers.adClicked), how could I to use webView.addJavascriptInterface() function to deal with it?
I know how to deal with single object, but I don't know how to deal with multi-object?

### I use following code, but it does not work:

```
enter code here
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "webkit");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "messageHandlers");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "adClicked");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "webkit.messageHandlers.thepaperNewsClicked");

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void postMessage(final String str) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "param：" + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
```

---

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView addJavascriptInterface does not work if the webview is created in the callback of WebChromeClient#onCreateWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749425/android-webview-addjavascriptinterface-does-not-work-if-the-webview-is-created-i)

Answer (score -1):

From android API document :

> void addJavascriptInterface (Object object, String name)

The parameter "name" is used to let javascript to call from android, so you can just deal with single object; you can create one class and put 
in functions which can been called for javascript, and give one name for javascript to call.

you can see what they do in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24060790/8355528

Reference site:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html