# Android WebView: loadurl() while replacing some string

Tags: android, webview

I use webview.loadurl(URL) to download a webpage to my WebView. Is it possible to replace some strings in the webpage while downloading?

Comment: What do you mean by replacing strings in the webpage while downloading? You can't do that. Android doesn't support that to prevent people from stealing passwords or important info if a user writes that in the webView. But what you can do is building an html string to show it in your webView.

Comment: I followed this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518950 to manipulate HTML content. One problem with is that the onPageFinished() is not called after inner loadUrl() is done.

Comment: Use a http component to download the page. Manupilate it. Load in WebView.

Comment: Use a http component to download the page is good to the first page. if users click a link in the page, the next page will be loaded to the WebView automatically. We have no chance to use a http component to download the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Javascript and load it using the loadData method with the prefix "javascript:". For example, loading "javascript:window.alert('Hello');" will show a hello message. You can parse the DOM and replace strings instead of the alert message.