# Issue with editing of Path authentication page

Tags: javascript, android, authentication, webview

So I have next issue. My app export some images to Path(some social network, as I think), and I use Amazon appstore for sharing my app. But the authentication page of Path, which I fetch in webview has a link to Apple Store and Google Play Market, that's very bad, because of amazon policy disallows such links and I can't publish my app. Here is example of such authentication page - https://partner.path.com/oauth2/authenticate?response_type=code&client_id=1b81bf92642176a90222d90c5ca5c2c6937f4dd7.

First of all, I tried to find some way to edit downloaded page - use javascript to get code of page, delete a link and fetch it back to webview. But after such manipulations webview stop to respond on clicks and I can't log in. I done smth like in this post - [Is it possible to get the HTML code from WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479833/is-it-possible-to-get-the-html-code-from-webview).

So I ask your help guys in next issue - I need working variant of authentication page of Path without any links to any markets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everybody! It's not possible to edit the page in way it will working correctly after it. So I was forced to delete this function from my app.

Also I have written an email to Path team - they just answered that they don't going to change their authentication page in near future.